# Remotely Compiling a project by Accessing limited files

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, keil, iar

I am facing a genuine problem and not sure what exactly are the keywords for the same.
    I have a c project and using Embedded arm tool chain to build it.There is a configuration file and some C/C++ Linker settings of Macros/hash Defines which needs to be changed for a a given configuration.
    Customer keeps asking us to change those configuration and build and send the binaries to the customer.There is now 100s of such combinations and the task is quiet monotonous and cumbersome.
    We dont want to say NO to customer , also don't want to share this source code.
    I am thinking of a system(web based or any other thing) where the customer has the access to these files and he can invoke the build commands by changing this file and passing the MACROS on the command lines and get the binaries.
    How can I achieve it?

`Update` : I have googled and talked to few people and teh answer is this can be partially Achieved using `Jenkins`

Comment: This sounds like a very complex thing. Do the defines need to be defined at compile time? In ideal situation you'd have only one binary, and user could change the settings through UI or serial port API or partial flashing.

Comment: Yes Compile time settings not on Runtime via some UI,API or Serial Ports.